# Приведение const char* к char*

Tags: c++, qt5

Пытаюсь с `QByteArray` получить указатель на данные с помощью `data()`, 
ругается:

> ```
> ошибка: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
> char * TempPtrBuff = ARes.data();
> ```

В документации пишется, что возвращается `char *`.

Почему может возникать ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте `const char * TempPtrBuff = ARes.data();` или `char * TempPtrBuff = const_cast<char*>ARes.data();` в зависимости от того что хотите получить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результат вывода `QByteArray::data()` зависит от константности метода, в котором производится вызов обозначенной функции. Проще говоря:

```
void MyClass::method() {
    char *data = ARes.data();
}

void MyClass::method() const {
    const char *data = ARes.data();
}
```

Соответственно, если вывод `QByteArray::data()` отличен от желаемого, то измените константность метода или осуществите приведение типа, например, тем же `const_cast<T>()`.

Comment: @КонстантинФомин, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если член `ARes` объявлен как `mutable` в `MyClass`, то будет вызвана неконстантная версия `data()` несмотря на наличие `const` у `method`.

Comment: "зависит от константности метода"? Он зависит не от "константности метода" (тем более, что никакого метода мы в вопросе не видим), а от константности объекта `ARes`. Если `ARes` константен, то будет вызываться константная версия метода (и наоброот).

Comment: @alexolut, спасибо, не знал.

Comment: @AnT, речь в вопросе о Qt, а потому предположить, что проблема именно в методе было само собой разумеющимся. Другое дело, что наверное надо было как-то указать этот факт в ответе. Что касаемо константности объекта `ARes`, это - да, но я предположил, что у автора проблема в меньшей степени вероятности связана именно с этим.

Comment: @alexis031182 : Она в любом случае связано именно с этим. "Константность метода" - это ни что иное, как константность объекта `*this` и, как следствие, константность его члена `this->ARes`. Все в конечном итоге сводится к константности (или не константности) именно `ARes`.

Comment: @AnT, теперь понял, о чём Вы. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: `const_cast<T>()` — не надо этого делать. Если метод объявлен константным, значит логика программы может быть на эту константность завязана. Ну или `ARes` может быть банально размещён в секции только для чтения.

Answer (score 1):

`QByteArray::data()` имеет перегрузки по наличию константности у объекта `QByteArray`, для которого данная функция вызывается.

Если контекст использования результата вызова `data()` подразумевает возможность изменения данных через полученный указатель, то нужно использовать именно неконстантный объект `QByteArray` и использовать тип `char*` для переменной. Если при этом возникает ошибка как в Вашем вопросе, значит Вы собираетесь изменить данные константного объекта. Это говорит об ошибке в проектировании объемлющего класса (исхожу из предположения, что `QByteArray` в Вашем случае является членом класса).

Если результат `data()` не предполагается изменять, то на константность объекта `QByteArray` можно не обращать внимания, а просто использовать `const char*` для переменной.

Попытка убрать константность через `const_cast` может кончится плачевно (UB), если используемый объект действительно константен.

Пример, актуальный для любого типа `T`:

```
T obj;
const T& cref = T;
T& ref = const_cast<T&>(cref); // OK, т.к. cref реально ссылается на неконстантный объект

const T obj;
const T& cref = T;
T& ref = const_cast<T&>(cref); // Плохо, т.к. cref реально ссылается на константный объект
```

Попытка модифицировать `obj` через ссылку `ref` во втором случае приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Другой способ избежать ошибки в строке инициализации  `TempPtrBuff` - использовать `auto`:

```
auto TempPtrBuff = ARes.data();
```

Но это всё равно не даст возможности модифицировать константный объект.